# Can't get token from firebase messaging on Ios device usb

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript

I tried to test my app on an Ios device via usb.
I managed to load my application on the phone with xcode, it seems to work fine.
This application has been made with Nativescript + VueJs and I want to test notifications with Firebase Messaging (this works fine on android).

The problem that I have is that I can't get the uniq token from FCM and I got this message :

APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '**********'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.

I don't know what to do, I request permission has in this page : https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/firebase-messaging.html#ios-requesting-permissions

```
    import { firebase } from '@nativescript/firebase-core'
import '@nativescript/firebase-messaging' // only needs to be imported 1x

async function requestUserPermission() {
  const authStatus = await firebase()
    .messaging()
    .requestPermission({
      ios: {
        alert: true
      }
    })
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus)

    const didRegister = await firebase().messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages()
  }
}
```

The prompt alert works fine and I "allow" notifications, but the I can't get the token from FCM for Firebase-messaging....

This is not a test on simulator, it is a test on a real device...

Thanks for any suggestion or solution !